# Install Magento 2.1 with MariaDB

Tags: magento, mariadb, magento2, magento2.1

Current system installed is using MySQL, going forward we decided to move from MySQL to MariaDB. MySQL service has been stopped and created new DB using HeidiSQL which comes after MariaDB installation.

[image: MariaDB Table]

Now while installing Magento 2.1, I am facing below error.

[image: Magento Error]

How do I install Magento 2.1 with MariaDB ? Currently I am using WAMPP server.

Answer (score 2):

try using localhost as the hostname in the configuration 
also, try creating a new user for your database with host %

Comment: The issue is, during magento installation,  could not connect to MariaDB and it connects to MySQL everytime. How do I tell Magento to connect to MariaDB instead of MySQL ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set-up your firewall settings and open up ports for MariaDB (SQL during installation does that for you, so you didn't have to do it manually). Also add another user with privileges you need, it's never smart to use root for all of your access.

You can follow some steps on [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) link, for configuring remote access. It should be the same for the local configuration, at least the same ports.